# Display both image and label in DataGrid column header

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and previously I was only displaying Image/Icon in the column header using the following `Style`.

```
            <Style  TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" >
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StrToImageConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

I am passing the image path as column name in my `DataTable`

```
    string colName; // Some file path
    DataColumn c = new DataColumn(colName) { DataType = typeof(string) };
    dt.Columns.Add(c);
```

and `StrToImageConverter` converts it to bitmap.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ImageSource result = null;
        string path = (string)value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            result = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

        return result;
    }
```

But now I also have to display the column name as text along with the icon. I can add a `TextBlock` in the `StackPanel` next to image but I'm not sure how to pass data to it or is it even the best approach.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your underlying ItemsSource object contains property you can simply bind Text with that property.

But as it is evident from your question you are binding it with DataTable. You can `add another column` in DataTable say `HeaderName` and bind with it -

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StrToImageConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderName}"/>
</StackPanel>
```